# Make windows ask for admin password for standard users

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-8.1, security

I have some windows7 and windows 8 machines, In each machine, there are two accounts, An administrator, and a standard user, When I sign in as the standard user and navigate to the desktop (with file explorer) of the Administrator windows asks me for the latter's password, And that's expectable, So I enter the password and I get access to the desktop.

Now when I close file explorer and try to navigate again to the same folder I still have access and windows don't ask for the password again, So is there any way I can change this behavior? I looked in the Local Security Policy but couldn't find anything!

In general, I will be performing some operations that require admin privilege on the Standard User account and I don't want the "password" or the admin access to be saved for that user at all.

Comment: I'm pretty sure there's some sort of timeout on this (or it should ask every time it needs permission); I'll get back to you on this!

Comment: I've found this; I'm not sure if it helps: https://superuser.com/questions/1114884/windows-10-administrator-permissions

Comment: I think you're confusing two things. In the first paragraph you're accessing files, and when windows prompts you for the Administrator password it's in order to give you file access. In the last paragraph you want to do what is known as process elevation. In the case of file access, once permission has been granted, it remains unless manually revoked, whereas by process elevation, it applies on a per-process basis, and does not remain for reuse.